Making a List with Arithmetic Progression
[Doing an assignment where I have to have to run the formula a(n) = 2*n - 5 (n>=1)] 100 times and have those in a list so that I can grab terms and compare and bunch of other stuff. This is what my code looks like.](https://i.sstatic.net/cWovhIcg.png)
I'll also type it out here:
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class QuanTest 
{
    List<Integer> daList = new ArrayList<>();

    
    public void listMaker (int start, int diff, int term)
    {
        int curr_term = start;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(curr_term);
            daList.add(curr_term);
            curr_term = ((2*curr_term) -5);
        }
    }

    //where the magic happens
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        listMaker(2,1,4);
    }
}

The error I'm running into right now is: non-static method listMaker(int,int,int) cannot be referenced from a static context.
I'm a beginner so I don't know what that means or if the problem is actual with how I'm even approaching this. Help.
I would like for the for loop to run 100 times and on every loop create a new term and add that to the list. It isn't doing that.

This actual your homework, please read more tutorial.

strongly recommended to learn about static methods (and fields)  Usually there are two solutions to "non-static method listMaker(int,int,int) cannot be referenced from a static context." : 1) make the method static; 2) call it from a non-static context -- both is kind of basic in Java, not meant simple nor easy, more like essential knowledge

( Oracle's Java tutorial Understanding Class Members - eventually the whole Lesson: Classes and Objects )

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class ArithmeticProgression {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Define the first term, common difference, and the size of the progression
        int firstTerm = 5;
        int commonDifference = 3;
        int size = 10;

        // Generate the list using Stream API
        List<Integer> apList = IntStream.range(0, size)
                                        .map(i -> firstTerm + i * commonDifference)
                                        .boxed()  // Convert to Integer stream
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // Output the arithmetic progression list
        System.out.println(apList);
    }
}


Like your other answers, you don't explain what the code does nor how it works. The posted question is essentially asking why the code (in the question) is causing the error: non-static method ... cannot be referenced from a static context Pardon me, but how is your answer related to that question?

Code-dump answers with code and no separate textual explanation do not help future visitors which is the purpose of this site. Please review the [answer] link and then consider editing and improving this answer.
